# Scenario for uploading images with an article

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, naming-conventions

I am having a little bit tricky situation. 
1)  I want to let the user to write articles and they can upload images with article. 
2)  To create the folder while the user is writing and uploading the images I want to name   the folder for the images with same ArticleId in the database for the article that is yet to created. So that folder can be identified for that article.

Now if the Id for the article is generated and stored in the `Session["ArticleId"]`. That will be used in the creation of the ImageFolder for the article. The bad thing is that the Imagefolder has to be created first.  The case is that the user can simultaneously write two article. So the Session does not make sense.

If I store this ArticleId in Hiddenfield on the page then later someone can manipulate the Id and that shows a danger to later create a unique entry with that id in the database. So I am wondering what else can I do??? 
**Note**
I am using Guid for the Id

Answer (score 0):

Create a random integer, and/or id based on the user, then use this in creating both the unique article id and file id of anything they upload.

Comment: There are lots of ways to go with this.  You could put the unique identifier into session after you've created the article, then pull it to create the image id, then set your session variable to null.  You could have a global variable on the page that you set the id with and then null out after you are done with it.  Or a hidden input. Personally, I would probably create a global variable.  Just make sure you handle the setting and defaulting correctly so it is ready for subsequent articles and uploads.  Good luck!

Comment: how to do it with session variable. for one article it is ok.. but what about write two or three articles at the same time. Like all the three browser windows are open at the same time. So How to identify then?

Comment: That's where the random generation comes in, maybe a 4-digit number between 0001 and 9999?  As for multiple windows, perhaps you want to generate the random ID in Javascript and then pass it into your server code?   These are just ideas my friend, I have not done something like this.